# setting global vars in eslint-plugin-import

Tags: global-variables, eslint, eslint-plugin-import

How can I in my .eslintrc.js file set what global variables are uesed, eslint-plugin-import is returning an error -> `3:30  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'config'  import/no-unresolved`. Another way would be to ignore 'config' I guess?

Kind regards

If I set

```
'import/no-unresolved': 'off'
```

then obviously it's working but not as intended, I want the rule to exist just not for global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can define globales like this

```
{
  "globals": {
    "foo": true
  }
}
```